# How to Extract all IDs from this XML?

Tags: c#, xml

How can i extract all the elements inside this xml file,the number of elements can vary also

```
<root response="True">
<Movie Title="The Wolf of Wall Street" Year="2013" imdbID="tt0993846" Type="movie"/>
<Movie Title="Brotherhood of the Wolf" Year="2001" imdbID="tt0237534" Type="movie"/>
<Movie Title="Wolf Creek" Year="2005" imdbID="tt0416315" Type="movie"/>
<Movie Title="Teen Wolf" Year="2011–" imdbID="tt1998328" Type="series"/>
<Movie Title="Teen Wolf" Year="2011–" imdbID="tt1567432" Type="series"/>
<Movie Title="Wolf" Year="1994" imdbID="tt0111742" Type="movie"/>
<Movie Title="Teen Wolf" Year="1985" imdbID="tt0090142" Type="movie"/>
<Movie Title="The Wolf Man" Year="1941" imdbID="tt0034398" Type="movie"/>
<Movie Title="Hour of the Wolf" Year="1968" imdbID="tt0063759" Type="movie"/>
<Movie Title="Jin-Roh: The Wolf Brigade" Year="1999" imdbID="tt0193253" Type="movie"/>
</root>
```

i need to extract all the IDs attribute of movie and im programming in c#

Comment: Write an xpath expression.  There are a million examples on the web.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way beside XPath is, using LINQ-to-XML and [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path_to_xml_file.xml");
List<string> Ids = doc.Root
                      .Elements("Movie")
                      .Select(o => (string)o.Attribute("imdbID"))
                      .ToList();
```